# How to set up a JavaFX program with one stage but multiple scenes with Scenebuilder/FXML

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, fxml, scene

So, I'm pretty new to JavaFX and completely new to Scenebuilder and FXML, what I want to do, to start, is have one stage and two windows(scenes) with a button each, and the buttons switch the window/scene to the opposite one. This was no problem using just JavaFX code, using just `button1.setOnAction(e -> stage.setScene(scene2))` etc, but I haven really managed to do the same thing with FMXL. I've set up controller classes with `fx:id` and `onAction` methods, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the stage/scenes from there.

So, if anyone could show me how to set up a basic program with one main/application class (the one with `main()` and `start()` method), two controller classes and two FXML classes, including how to correctly initialize/run the program, that would be a huge help to a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this video [1 Stage Multi-scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RifjriAxbw8).
This helped me out with the same issue.

The idea is to have a central StageManager do all the scene switching.